# list all globally installed modules with one command in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-cli

I'm working on **`ubuntu 14.04`**, Is there any way to print all global  modules (installed using **`npm`**) to the command line. How can I do this?

Comment: `npm list -g` ?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The below command will list all your globally installed modules on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

```
npm ls -g --depth 0
```

Comment: why is there such a massive difference with and without the `--depth 0` option? Do I or don't I have all these dependencies installed globally as well?

Comment: The difference with `--depth 0` is that with that option you are only listing packages that are *directly* globally installed.  Without the depth option you are also listing all the packages that are dependencies of those packages.

Answer (score 20):

To list all globally installed modules run:

```
npm ls -g --depth 0
```

or yarn

```
yarn global ls --depth 0
```

**Extras:**

To get a short module description run:

```
npm ll -g --depth 0
```

To see the path of where the global modules are installed run:

```
npm ls -gp --depth 0
```

Answer (score 6):

My preferred method is to use the [npmlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmlist) package, which can be installed using `npm i -g npmlist`. Then you just use the `npmlist` command to get a formatted and color listing with versions of all global packages.

```sh
$ npmlist

Installed npm packages: (global)

@vue/cli.................[3.5.1]
browser-sync............[2.26.3]
degit....................[2.1.3]
eslint..................[5.15.3]
eslint-plugin-vue........[5.2.2]
jsonlint.................[1.6.3]
npm......................[6.9.0]
npmlist..................[3.1.2]
prettier................[1.16.4]
serverless..............[1.39.1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Much faster command than the selected answer, if you care only about listing package name and not the package version:

```
ls -l $(npm root -g)
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for packages like @postlight/mercury-parser.

Answer (score 0):

To see the list of all globally installed modules type the following command:

`npm ls -g --depth 0`

this will give you the list of all the installed modules along with their versions.
Even unmet dependencies if any, will also be listed.

Comment: It is the exact same command as in the accepted answer (which is the most visible answer)

Answer (score 0):

The previous global and local flags are now deprecated. The preferred syntax today is as follows:

```bash
npm list --location=global --depth 0
npm ls   --location=global --depth 0
npm la   --location=global --depth 0
npm ll   --location=global --depth 0

npmlist=$(npm list --location=global --depth 0)
npmlist
```